# How to use “pretty” ironically

Tags: phrase-meaning

Here is a quote from Peter Benchley’s Jaws: “That’s a pretty shitty trick.”

I would like to know how common this expression is in English, and under what circumstances/instances is used. (That is, what exactly it means and what ironic degree do we have here).

I know that “pretty” can be used ironically, but to me as a non native, it sounds pretty odd.

So, would you please explain it in detail so that I can get a better understanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this quote *pretty* is an informal intensifier meaning "very".  It strengthens the following adjective, *shitty*, which is an informal and rude word with a negative meaning, here expressing that Harry's trick was reprehensible.

I don't think any irony is involved here.

Comment: Thank you so much, so, it’s rudeness not irony! Duly noted!

Comment: I think OP was confused because some dictionaries list "pretty" being used ironically: [See sense 2.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pretty) I think you should make a distinction between *ironic pretty* and *adverbial pretty* as an addendum.

Comment: @LucianSava "pretty" is not rude in itself - it's the "shitty" here that is rude! One can say, for example, "That was a pretty good movie". It's a soft intensifier - it wasn't a great movie, but it was better than good!